# Can I use NumberPicker control from android in JavaFX project?

Tags: javafx, numberpicker

I'm developing project for Raspberry Pi 3 on JavaFX and for UI I need control like android NumberPicker and it's interesting for me, can I use NumberPicker control from android in JavaFX project?

Comment: don't know (doubt it though, if NumberPicker is a native android control) - but what happened when you tried?

Comment: I haven't try, It'll be my second question)) Can I use and if I can, how?) Now I think it can not be done. It just seemed to me that this is a pretty "popular" control and it should be in JavaFX

Comment: Have you tried JavaFX on the Raspberry Pi before? It doesn't work right out of the box.

Comment: Yes, but I use JavaFX from Bellsoft. I don't have a lot expirience in it, but it's work for me